# Defaultly sorting the values in IE 9 and chrome using with DWR

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, dwr

I have a map contains years information in UI class as {'2012':"2012",'2011':"2011",'2010':"2010"} , If I pass this map to javascript to build dropdown using DWR, Firefox displays the drop down as we passed But in IE9 and chrome the values are sorting and it is displaying from 2010 to 2012 in drop down. May I know why it is building like this ?. Can anyone help on this Issue.

I am using dwr 2.0 version.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using *for..in* to iterate over the object properties then you should know that the order in which they are returned is implementation dependent and is not guaranteed to follow any particular system or pattern.

It is also known that different browsers will return the properties in a different order. If order is important, use some other method to determine the order and use the object only to allocate values to property names.

Comment: Thanks for reply...when I iterate the map in js with firefox the values are coming as we passed from UI class but only in IE9 and chrome the values are coming in sorting order. This is working in fine in IE8 and IE7. Shall I know how to avoid the order in IE9 and chrome? any meta tags? or?

Comment: There is **no way** to guarantee the order in which object properties are returned, ECMA-262 §2.6.4 says quite explicitly that the order is implementation dependent, and as you have discovered it can be different between versions of the same browser. Use some other method to (as suggested in my answer) to determine order.

Comment: @RobG Thanks for your reply. I was looking all around for this weird behavior. It should be marked as accepted!